# Wrapper function to parse multiple API requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I'm building a simple aggregator-type app that would pull in data from multiple websites (via their APIs) and then present the data on the same page. For example, on a search for *John Grisham*, the app would get data from his page from Wikipedia, his highest rated book from Goodreads and his author page from IMDb (and so on).

Right now I have the jQuery code for requesting and parsing the JSON response from these APIs separately, and then update the page using the `$.when`/`$.done` functions.

I'm trying to create a single function that would handle the AJAX requests, instead of having 5-6 different separate ones. But since each of these sites has a different API implementation for requesting and returning data, I can't make a catch-all function.

My approach so far has been somewhere in the middle - I create an object with the required parameters and response-parsing function like so:

```
var Search = {
    wikipedia: {
        url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?redirects&callback=?',
        param: {
            page: searchQuery,
            prop: 'text',
            action: 'parse',
            section: 0
        },
        template: function(response) {
            $('#wikipedia').html(response.parse.text['*']);
        }
    },
    imdb: {
        url: 'http://www.imdbapi.com/?callback=?',
        param: {
            t: searchQuery
        },
        template: function(response) {
            $('#imdb').html(response.Plot);
        }
    }
};
```

...and then loop through it to execute all the searches asynchronously, and on `success` execute the `template` method.

```
for (var eachSite in Search) {
    function searchDo (site) {
        $.ajax({
            url: site.url,
            data: site.param,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: site.template
        });
    };

    searchDo(Search[eachSite]);
}
```

This is the part I can't quite wrap my head around. Although it works, it doesn't seem quite right. Potentially the list of APIs to access would include around 10-15 sites.

Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Your options are limited if you intend to do all your requests from the client side.

Comment: Client-side would be preferable, but its certainly not my only option. I've never done any server-side parsing of JSON before though - I'm assuming it would be called in with a cURL (with PHP)?

Comment: I just read about `trait` in PHP 5.4 - maybe that would be a way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use $.when you could assign each request to a variable, push that variable into an array then use the array as arguments for $.when